# Regular Expression To Extract Names

Tags: regex, algorithm, regular-language

I have strings in this form:

```
"""00.000000 00.000000; X-XX000-0000-0; France; Paris; Street 12a;   
00.000000 00.000000; X-XX000-0000-0; Spain; Barcelona; Street 123;"""
```

I want to get specific data `towns` above string. How do I get this data??

Comment: Could you tell us something more about the string format? Is it a semicolon-seaprated fields `numbers; numbers; country; city; street`? Do you want only the cities?

Comment: That's how it looks like, yes, basically semicolon separated fields.

Comment: You can use `explode` semicolon separator.

Comment: This is basically a CSV file... you don't even need regex...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to get the city for your given example, you could use a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

[`\b[^;]+(?=;[^;]+;$)`](https://regex101.com/r/PkuJMU/1)

**Explanation**

```
\b        # Word boundary
[^;]+     # Match NOT ; one or more times
(?=       # Positive lookahead that asserts what follows is
   ;      # Match semicolon
   [^;]+  # Match NOT ; one or more times  
   ;      # Match ;
   $      # Match end of the string
)         # Close lookahead
```

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/oJ9VHX/1 Also, matching from the beginning, not just the city.

Comment: @RobHannigan I have updated my answer to select only the city.

Comment: I am usually not commenting on accepted answers but this expression is **incredibly ineffective**, see [**`^(?:[^;]+;){2}\s*([^;]+)`**](https://regex101.com/r/PkuJMU/2) (51 steps) in comparison to [**yours**](https://regex101.com/r/PkuJMU/1) (1214 steps). Here, more than **20 times** more steps are needed to achieve the same result. Lookarounds are "expensive" and really not needed in this situation. One really important thing in the `regex` world is to come to an end fast(er).

Comment: @Jan You are right and in my previous answer I used a different approach which was much more efficient but the OP wanted just the city selected.  But I totally agree.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Python` (three quotes-string):

```
string = """00.000000 00.000000; X-XX000-0000-0; France; Paris; Street 12a;   
00.000000 00.000000; X-XX000-0000-0; Spain; Barcelona; Street 123;"""

towns = [part[3] for line in string.split("\n") for part in [line.split("; ")]]
print(towns)
```

Which yields

```
['Paris', 'Barcelona']
```

No `regex` needed, really.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the city on the 4th field, you can match it using this pattern:

```
 /(?:[^;]*;){3}([^;]*);/
```

[See the demo](https://regex101.com/r/er2i5g/1)

`[^;]*;` you find a field consisting in non-semicolons and ending with a semicolon

`(?:...){3}` you find it 3 times, but you do not capture it

`([^;]*);` then you get 4th column matching its content (not the semicolon)

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/84haeF/1 Matching from the beginning, not just city.

Comment: String from the beginning is _matched_ but it it not _captured_ so only the city will appear in regexp operation results.